# MySQL: Merge entries in pivot table based on joined table duplicate entries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one of participants:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | First Name | Last Name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  0 | John       | Snow      |
|  1 | John       | Snow      |
|  2 | Michael    | Jackson   |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

And one pivot table which connects participants with events:

```
+----+----------------+----------+
| id | participant_id | event_id |
+----+----------------+----------+
|  0 |              0 |       12 |
|  1 |              1 |       35 |
|  2 |              2 |       35 |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

By mistake there are duplicate entries in the participants' table.

How I can delete duplicate entries in participants' table and update accordingly the pivot table? So the expected results will be :

participants:

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | First Name | Last Name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  0 | John       | Snow      |
|    |            |           | //deleted
|  2 | Michael    | Jackson   |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

pivot table:

```
+----+----------------+----------+
| id | participant_id | event_id |
+----+----------------+----------+
|  0 |              0 |       12 |
|  1 |              0 |       35 | //participant_id changed from 1 to 0
|  2 |              2 |       35 |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: So, in case of duplicates, you want to keep the first `id` value ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes

Answer (score 0):

This will be a multi-step process:

- First step is to update the mapping table `pivot`. Following query will give you all the names which are Duplicate, and the first `id` for them:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, MIN(id) AS first_id 
FROM participants 
GROUP BY first_name, last_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- more than one rows means duplicates exist
```

You can use the above query as a subquery to update the `pivot` table using a series of Joins:

```
UPDATE pivot AS m 
JOIN participants AS p1 
  ON p1.id = m.participant_id 
JOIN (
       SELECT first_name, last_name, MIN(id) AS first_id 
       FROM participants 
       GROUP BY first_name, last_name 
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) AS p2 ON p2.first_name = p1.first_name 
                AND p2.last_name = p1.last_name 
                AND p2.first_id <> p1.id  -- avoid the original row
SET m.participant_id = p2.first_id  -- update the duplicate row's id to first id
```

- Now, you can `DELETE` the duplicate rows using the same subquery (to find duplicates):

```
DELETE p1 FROM participants AS p1 
JOIN (
       SELECT first_name, last_name, MIN(id) AS first_id 
       FROM participants 
       GROUP BY first_name, last_name 
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) AS p2 ON p2.first_name = p1.first_name 
                AND p2.last_name = p1.last_name 
                AND p2.first_id <> p1.id  -- avoid the original row
```

- Finally, fix the problem at your data definition level, to avoid this happening again, by defining a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `(first_name, last_name)`

```
ALTER TABLE participants ADD CONSTRAINT unq_idx_name UNIQUE(first_name, last_name);
```